# Is there a library for neural networks that works with the Pi?

Tags: networking

I have a few Pis lying around and have been planning to learn about neural nets for a while. So far searching on google hasn't turned up many promising results.

Has anyone tried? Are there libraries that work on with RPi?

Comment: Have you looked at http://opennn.cimne.com ?

Comment: @medbot no first time hearing about it. Have you worked with it before?